# Jquery validation of multiple ckeckboxes array using jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery

I am having one isuue with jquery validatior plugin.
I have a form in which  all fields are loaded dynamically using ajax. all fields name and ids set dynamically. So i can not get their name into jquery.

Admin can set some fileds validation required true, or false.  Now my problem is for checkbox.  I set their name into  array . Also i am using pretty-checkbox custom class to apply style on checkbox.  For ex: one group chkbox array name start from : name= chkbox_30[]    ,   some other group of checkbox array name= check-box_25[]

GROUP1 :

```
 <input id="check-box_30" class="pretty_custom req_question" type="checkbox" size="100" onchange="return chk_ckbox(this.id);" data-label="opt2" value="opt2" name="check-box_30[]" style="display: none;"> 
<label for="check-box_30">opt2</label>

    <input id="check-box_30" class="pretty_custom req_question" type="checkbox" size="100" onchange="return chk_ckbox(this.id);" data-label="opt1" checked="checked" value="opt1" name="check-box_30[]" style="display: none;">
    <a class="checked " href="#"></a>
<label for="check-box_30">opt1</label>
```

GROUP 2:

```
<input id="check-box_25" class="pretty_custom" type="checkbox" size="100" data-label="1 color" checked="checked" value="1 color" name="check-box_25[]" style="display: none;">
<a class="checked " href="#"></a>
<label for="check-box_25">1 color</label>

<input id="check-box_25" class="pretty_custom" type="checkbox" size="100" data-label="4 color" value="4 color" name="check-box_25[]" style="display: none;">
<a class=" " href="#"></a>
<label for="check-box_25">4 color</label>

<input id="check-box_25" class="pretty_custom" type="checkbox" size="100" data-label="multi color" value="multi color" name="check-box_25[]" style="display: none;">
<a class=" " href="#"></a>
<label for="check-box_25">multi color</label>
```

For Group 1 checkbox  validation is required:  at least one chkbox required selected.
For Group 2 i don;t required any validation.

Can anybody help to solve this issue ?
how to validate  them. I also add one class to 'req_question'  which i required validation for them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function isFormValid()
{
    var requiredCBs = $('.req_question');
    var id = '';
    var flag = false;
    for(var i=0;i<requiredCBs.length; i++)
    {
        var ths = $(requiredCBs[i]);
        var thsId = ths.attr('id');
        if(id == '')
        {
            id = thsId; // For first element
            flag = false;
        }
        else
            if(id == thsId)
            {
                if(!flag) // No checkbox checked for this group
                    if(ths.is(':checked')
                         flag = true;
            }
            else
                if(id != thsId) // New group
                    if(flag)
                    {
                        id = thsId;
                        flag = false;
                    }
                    else
                        return false; // Previous group has no checkbox checked
     }
     return true; // All groups have at least one checkbox checked.
}
```

Comment: how to use it in jquery validator plugin ? i am using jquery validation plugin . <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
 
 $('#frmadditionalinfo').validate({ 
  
  ignore: ':hidden:not(".filereqire")'
 });
 </script>

Comment: The above code will work just fine. No need to use that plugin. Plugins are for general purposes. Your's is a special case.

Comment: but i am already use  that plugin for same form in which textbox , textarea , fileupload, drop-down  all type of controls are loaded dynamically. validation of all those fields are done perfectly. just issue with checkbox only.. ..i must use jquery validation plugin....